# Getting the number of the rows affected by update or insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I need to check how many rows are affected by update or insert (actually, only update at the moment). I created the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rows_affected()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    x INTEGER := -1;
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS x = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN x;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION rows_affected()
  OWNER TO alex1;
```

Then I updated a table and called this function, the result was zero. Then I inserted a row and called the function again and again the result was zero. What's up with it? And how do I check the amount of the rows that were affected by update or insert properly?

UPDATE:

This doesn't work as I expect, instead it always returns 0 as the amount of the rows affected:

```
SELECT rows_affected();

update email set email='fdsfds' where id = 1;

insert into email(email) values('fdsfsdfdsfds');

SELECT rows_affected();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When function/trigger is called, the new internal execution state structure is created (PLpgSQL_execstate) with ROW_COUNT value (eval_processed property) set to 0. So inside function you can get ROW_COUNT only for statements inside the same function. As a workaround you can pass sql statement as the text argument to this procedure and execute it inside.

Comment: does that mean I can only call ROW_COUNT within other functions? Look at my update please.

Comment: You can call it anywhere, but if you get ROW_COUNT inside function, then you get number of records affected in the scope of this function, not outside. So when you query "SELECT rows_affected();" in your sample, the new execution context for this function is created and its ROW_COUNT statistics is set to 0 by default. This function doesn't change any rows you'll always get this default zero value.